# permissions error running Console/cake

Tags: cakephp, file-permissions, chmod, cakephp-bake

I'm trying to run the cake console application for the first time. From the cake `app` folder I am running `Console/cake` then I get the following output

```
PHP Warning:  SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 314

Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 314

Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

 -app: app
 -working: /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/app
 -root: /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html
 -core: /var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path. To change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

[CORE] acl, api, bake, command_list, console, i18n, schema, server, test, testsuite, upgrade

To run an app or core command, type cake shell_name [args]
To run a plugin command, type cake Plugin.shell_name [args]
To get help on a specific command, type cake shell_name --help

Warning Error: SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in [/var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 314]

Warning Error: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'file_map' to File cache in [/var/www/virtual_host.com/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 310]
```

this is the output of ls -l

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Config
drwxrwxr-x 4 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Console
drwxrwxr-x 3 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Controller
-rw-rw-r-- 1 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman  701 Jul 16 14:17 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Lib
drwxrwxr-x 3 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Locale
drwxrwxr-x 4 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Model
drwxrwxr-x 2 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Plugin
drwxrwxr-x 4 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Test
drwxrwxrwx 6 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 2 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 Vendor
drwxrwxr-x 9 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 View
drwxrwxr-x 6 DevinCrossman DevinCrossman 4096 Jul 16 14:17 webroot
```

I tried modifying Config/core.php with the following based on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718331/ocasional-error-warning-when-cakephp-is-writing-to-the-cache/12724620#12724620)

```
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));
```

but it didn't change anything.

Anyone know what permissions I need to change? Is it normal to need to change the permissions on a clean install? (except for app/tmp I know that's normal)

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718331/ocasional-error-warning-when-cakephp-is-writing-to-the-cache/12724620#12724620

Comment: the file app/Console/cake needs to be executable and and app/tmp needs to be writeable by the webserver, and I dunno if apache(I guess) is part of the DevinCrossman group.

Comment: @AlexStallen just found out Apache is running as www-data and www-data is only a member of the www-data group.. should I add myself to the www-data group and change ownership of the cake directory to that group?

Comment: make the ownership DevinCrossman:www-data of your whole cake directory `sudo chown -R DevinCrossman:www-data .` while standing in the root of the vhost

Comment: @AlexStallen Excellent that worked.. if you make it an answer I'll accept it

Comment: done, nice to be able to help

Comment: @DevinCrossman The update you made to core.php will only have effect on new files created in the `tmp` directory, not on already existing ones. But this will prevent the problem to reappear if you use some CakeShell with a user that is not www-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the ownership DevinCrossman:www-data of your whole cake directory `sudo chown -R DevinCrossman:www-data .` while standing in the root of the vhost.

the webserver (member of www-data) needs to be able to write in app/tmp

Comment: This answer is not sufficient to prevent the problem to reappear if some more files have to be created by Cake in the `tmp` folder, as those new files owners would be `www-data:www-data` if they are created by Apache, or `DevinCrossman:DevinCrossman` if they are created by a Shell run by Devin. Therefore the permissions of the newly created files are important as well.

Comment: that part is already covered in the question itself to use two different Cache::configs, both with mask 0666

Answer (score 3):

The files in `app/tmp` are created with *mode* `664`, so users belonging to `www-data` (or the *group* Apache runs with) are allowed to change them.
[file-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-permissions) [cache](/questions/tagged/cache)

So running:

```
sudo adduser mich www-data
newgrp www-data
```

solved the problem for me.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should also

```
sudo adduser www-data mich
```

so that cache files created by mich can be accessed by www-data