# Facing a file permission error while running CakePHP 3.0 in Linux

Tags: linux, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was able to deploy my application in Linux but i am facing one issue as mentioned below.

```
     Warning (512):SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/html/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_email_queue): 
                   failed to open stream: Permission denied 
                   [CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 391]

     Warning (512):SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/html/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_email_queue) 
                   [splfileinfo.openfile]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 391]

     Warning (512):cake_model cache was unable to write 'default_email_queue' to Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine cache 
                   [CORE/src/Cache/Cache.php, line 223].
```

I referred few links and tried all those but still in vain.

[CakePHP 2.x warning SplFileInfo due to cakeshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251362/cakephp-2-x-warning-splfileinfo-due-to-cakeshell)

[SplFileInfo::openFile(/app/tmp/cache/persistent/cake_core_cake_console_):failed to open stream:Permission denied in /lib/.../FileEngine.php line 293](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733498/splfileinfoopenfile-app-tmp-cache-persistent-cake-core-cake-console-failed)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is confusing about those warning messages?

Comment: It is terminating when i try to save some changes in my application or any changes in session. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you _read_ the warning messages? Have you put the text "failed to open stream: Permission denied" in google?

Comment: yes , searched on that.. and tried all those..still sometime iam geting these warnings

Comment: Well there's not really any ambiguity here - _look_ (and add to the question) at the permissions of the tmp folder and files. Obviously "sometimes" you don't have permission to write to those locations. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/tmp`

If you using ubuntu:
`sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/tmp`

### Note:

Your account must have `chmod` privilege