# cakephp: warning 512 /tmp/cache/ not writable on shared host justhost 1

Tags: cakephp

in localhost this was running successfully but when to put on to server i was showing these type of error please please give some suggestion how to rectify

Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-gb' to File cache in C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 323 Warning: C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\app\tmp\cache\persistent\ is not writable in C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php on line 384 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\app\Config\core.php(336): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Core\Configure.php(72): include('C:\websites\Odi...') #3 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\app\webroot\index.php(97): include('C:\websites\Odi...') #5 C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\index.php(41): require('C:\websites\Odi...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\websites\Odisha24x7\odisha24x7_cpanel\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 181

Comment: give write access to your root directory

Comment: Your /app/tmp directory needs to be writable.

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18220351/851885

Comment: @MoyedAnsari it is a pretty stupid idea to give *write* access on the root folder of a web application. *Always* only make read / writeable what has to be read / writeable. **Nothing** else. The root (folder) of the app is clearly *not* required to be writeable. In a correct setup **only** app/tmp is writeable.

Answer (score 2):

Give recursive permission to tmp dir inside app like as following:-

chmod -R 0777 /var/www/test-project/app/tmp

Comment: how is to write on tmp dir. can i create some file on temp dir.please give me suggestion in detail .thank you very much for your valuable suggestion