# CakePHP error: cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, cakephp, lamp

When I run my CakePHP application on localhost Ubuntu 14.04 (LAMP) I get this error:

> Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to
>   File cache in /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 328
>
> Warning: /var/www/html/tmc/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable
>   in /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache
>   engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured. Ensure required
>   extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct' in
>   /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:186 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151):
>   Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1
>   /var/www/html/tmc/app/Config/core.php(386):
>   Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2
>   /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72):
>   include('/var/www/html/t...') #3
>   /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(431):
>   Configure::bootstrap(true) #4
>   /var/www/html/tmc/app/webroot/index.php(97):
>   include('/var/www/html/t...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186

I am not sure where is the issue. I tried `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/tmc/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php` command but it didn't fix  the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp cake\_core\_ cache was unable to write 'cake\_dev\_en-us'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220128/cakephp-cake-core-cache-was-unable-to-write-cake-dev-en-us)

Comment: `I tried sudo chmod 775 .../FileEngine.php` Did you really expect that to do anything, I think you misread the error message; this is pretty unambiguous `Warning: .../tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable`

Comment: The webserver needs write access to the tmp folder, answer is below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running apache or nginx (fast-cgi) as user `www-data` that user should be the owner of the file:

```
cd /var/www/html/tmc/app;

find tmp -type d -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 chmod 2755;
find tmp -type f -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 chmod 0644;

chown -R www-data:www-data tmp;
```