# CakePHP and Memcached error - php5.6

Tags: php, cakephp, memcached, php-5.6

I'm trying to migrate our company application from php 5.3 to php 5.6. This app uses cakephp 2.4.3 and memcached, but when I try to execute ./cake bake command, the next error comes up:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_')
#1 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/app/Config/core.php(381): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array)
#2 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/cluster/data/d...')
#3 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(177): Configure::bootstrap(true)
#4 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(136): require('/cluster/data/d...')
#5 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(98): ShellDispatcher->_bootstrap()
#6 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(54): ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment()
#7 /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/cu in /cluster/data/deploy/clickdelivery/current/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181
```

Persistent and models directory are created with +W.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enabled memcached model in php5.6 ? you can do php -m  | grep memcached to check

Comment: Yeah man, its enabled.

Comment: Then did you restart your web server?

Comment: Lot of votes on this... folder permissions?  Not sure if it writes to disk for model proxies then memcached...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220128/cakephp-cake-core-cache-was-unable-to-write-cake-dev-en-us

Comment: CakePHP uses the cli version of php for Console applications (including bake). Do you have memcached enabled in both the webserver and cli php files?