# Cakephp cache not writable error message

Tags: php, cakephp, file-permissions, chmod

I have `Fedora18` and was trying to install `cakephp` . But it shows

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 323

Warning: /var/www/html/cakem2/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /var/www/html/cakem2/app/Config/core.php(374): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/html/c...') #3 /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /var/www/html/cakem2/app/webroot/index.php(94): include('/var/www/html/c...') #5 /var/www/html/cakem2/index.php(41): require('/var/www/html/c...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/cakem2/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181
```

Following the answers [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220128/cakephp-cake-core-cache-was-unable-to-write-cake-dev-en-us), I have made all the directory and sub-directory writable as shown in [image: Screenshot]. But I am still getting the error ! Whats wrong ?

Comment: This question & answer may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8879796/3728901

Answer (score 2):

chown the folders / files so that the user matches the user which httpd or Apache uses to access these files. I don't know the user for fedora, i think its apache or httpd. In ubuntu its www-data.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Administration_Guide_Draft/Apache