# AWS CakePHP - tmp directory needs to be writeable

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, tmp

I have a server set up on AWS and i ahve deployed my application to it, like i have done many time to other servers.
After turning core.php debug to 2, the following error showed

> Warning: /var/www/html/XXX/XXX/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/html/XXX/XXX/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 389

This is a common warning i recieve any time i pull down the code from git.

As usual i run

```
chmod -R 777 tmp
```

And I still recieve the warning, which doesnt let me proceed until i fix it!

I have tried to rename the tmp folder

> mv tmp tmp1

and i get this

> mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/XXX/XXX/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 384

Which is the warning that shows when you dont have a tmp folder in your app folder.

I have tried to changed the folder user group to apache:apache too and still no luck.

The error logs show nothing apart from the ones i get when i refresh the page.

Comment: Can you configure it to use a temp directory outside of the web root? It seems to be a bad place to allow writing to anyway. If someone found the path they could upload malicious PHP code and be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

change owner of the directory .

```
for example
  chown nginx:nginx ../tmp
  chown apache:apache ../tmp
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879614/facing-a-file-permission-error-while-running-cakephp-in-ubuntu-10-4

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was the problem. SELinux was set to enforcing

> /etc/selinux/config

Set it to permissive and it works fine now

Comment: hmm...SELinux was blocking that for a reason. It's dangerous to allow writing to directories under the web root.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Installation Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#permissions) of **CakePHP**

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | 
grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs
```